Why do some Siddurim say mitzvot tluyim ba instead of tluyot?
In the part between Borchi Nafshi and the Tallis blessing there is a kavona part that ends with mitzvot tluyim ba in some siddurim.
I first thought this was a mere typo but I've now seen it in quite a few versions.
